# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory instabot error

Tags: python

I have built a simple instagram bot with instabot however it is giving me the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\sianu\instagram_bot> & C:/Users/sianu/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/sianu/instagram_bot/main.py
The json file does not exist
[]
2021-07-30 08:25:31,552 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
2021-07-30 08:25:31,559 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2021-07-30 08:25:34,519 - INFO - Logged-in successfully as '1970s_sheffield'!
2021-07-30 08:25:34,519 - INFO - LOGIN FLOW! Just logged-in: True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\sianu\instagram_bot\main.py", line 42, in <module>
    upload_post(filename)
  File "c:\Users\sianu\instagram_bot\main.py", line 30, in upload_post
    bot.upload_photo(filename,
  File "C:\Users\sianu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\instabot\bot\bot.py", line 806, in upload_photo
    return upload_photo(self, photo, caption, upload_id, from_video, options)
  File "C:\Users\sianu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\instabot\bot\bot_photo.py", line 26, in upload_photo
    result = self.api.upload_photo(
  File "C:\Users\sianu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api.py", line 825, in upload_photo
    return upload_photo(
  File "C:\Users\sianu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api_photo.py", line 132, in upload_photo
    if not compatible_aspect_ratio(get_image_size(photo)):
  File "C:\Users\sianu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api_photo.py", line 197, in get_image_size
    with open(fname, "rb") as fhandle:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Ashgate Road.jpg'
2021-07-30 08:25:47,452 - INFO - Total requests: 31
PS C:\Users\sianu\instagram_bot>
```

My code is as follows:

```
from instabot import Bot
import os 

def delete_files():
    if os.path.exists("config/*cookie.json"):
        os.remove("config/*cookie.json")
    else: 
        print("The json file does not exist")

    directory = "C:/Users/sianu/instagram_bot/img"
    files_in_directory = os.listdir(directory)
    filtered_files = [file for file in files_in_directory if file.endswith(".REMOVE_ME")]
    print(filtered_files)
    for file in filtered_files:
        path_to_file = os.path.join(directory, file)
        os.remove(path_to_file)

def get_picture():
    directory = "C:/Users/sianu/instagram_bot/img"
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
            return filename

def upload_post(filename):
    bot = Bot()
    bot.login(username = "xxx",
        password = "xxx")
    hashtags = " #sheffield #1970ssheffield #1970s #vintagepics #cities #1970scities #city #cityonthemove #sheffieldissuper"
    
    bot.upload_photo(filename,
                    caption = filename + hashtags)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    delete_files()
    filename = get_picture()
    upload_post(filename)
```

I have tried calling just the get_picture() method and printing the file name and it can do this without an issue, so I'm not sure why when it tries to upload this file it says there is no such file? The code has also previously worked in the past so I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: Have you tried referencing the absolute path to the file in ```bot.upload_photo()```?

Comment: `listdir` gives only `filename` and you should join it with directory to get `full path` to file - `return os.path.join(directory, filename)`. Without full path it searchs image in wrong directory and it can't find it. See also `Current Working Directory` using `os.getcwd()` to see in which folder it searchs image.